# Withdrawing ETH from a Locked-out Account - Need Help!

Tags: wallets, private-key, import, wallet-transfer, recovery

I have some ETH on LocalCryptos.com (now shut down), but unfortunately, I have lost my access to the 2FA code, though I do have the password and a wallet backup file in JSON format.
I managed to recover and export 2700 private keys using their tool named LocalCryptosWalletBackupExplorer.

Now, I'm seeking advice on the best and possibly quickest approach to import all these bulk private keys from my inaccessible account to a wallet where I can either securely store them or further transfer them to an exchange for selling.